# Using two Threadpools at once

Tags: python, multithreading

I am just trying to get my head around ThreadPool in Python and I was trying to think of a case in which one pool of threads produce data while the other pool consumes it.

Below is my naive attempt at it :

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from time import sleep
import threading
import random

final_results = {}

def sample_function(n):
    threadname = threading.current_thread().name
    print(f"Starting execution of thread with the name {threadname} and argument {n}")
    sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    print(f"About to finish executing for thread name {threadname}")
    return n ** 2

def sample_function2(number, lock):
    threadname = threading.current_thread().name
    print(f"Starting execution of thread from 2nd pool with the name {threadname} and working on number {number}")
    with lock:
        final_results[number] = number * 2
    print(f"Completing execution of thread with the name {threadname}")


pool2 = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
numbers1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    lock = threading.Lock()
    futures = []
    for result in executor.map(sample_function, numbers1):
        future = pool2.submit(sample_function2, (result, lock))
        futures.append(future)

for future in futures:
    while not future.done():
        sleep(2)

print("Everything is done ... checking results now !")
print(final_results)
```

This is what I get as output:

```
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0 and argument 1
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1 and argument 2
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2 and argument 3
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2 and argument 4
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1 and argument 5
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0 and argument 6
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0
Everything is done ... checking results now !
{}
```

So why isn't any thread from the second pool starting up? Where am I going wrong because I also don't see any error message(Also please guide me why).

Is this the right way to approach a problem this was or do the thread pools use some sort of queue to communicate among themselves?

But in either case, I have to make the second pool functional.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what is at least a partial answer to your question with fixes the problem with the second pool not "starting up". There were several reasons for this.

Two of them were that you weren't calling `pool2.submit()` correctly nor getting the result from it (you need append the value returned from *calling* `future.result`).

Since the values that end up in the `futures` list are all `None` because `sample_function2()` doesn't return anything, the `while not future.done():` didn't work because each element is `None` and doesn't have `done` method to call, so I removed the entire `for future in futures:` loop — which isn't necessary anyway because by that point all the threads submitted have finished due the way the previous loop is written (i.e. calling `submit()` and then immediately waiting for it to finish by calling `result()`).

This means that this whole two approach using two `Pool`s doesn't do that much concurrent processing and therefore isn't making good use of the ability. That said, I don't really understand why you feel you must have them - so it's difficult to know what to recommend that you do instead.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep
import threading
import random

final_results = {}

def sample_function(n):
    threadname = threading.current_thread().name
    print(f"Starting execution of thread with the name {threadname} and argument {n}")
    sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    print(f"About to finish executing for thread name {threadname}")
    return n ** 2

def sample_function2(number, lock):
    threadname = threading.current_thread().name
    print(f"Starting execution of thread from 2nd pool with the name {threadname} and working on number {number}")
    with lock:
        final_results[number] = number * 2
    print(f"Completing execution of thread with the name {threadname}")


numbers1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

pool2 = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    lock = threading.Lock()
    futures = []
    for result in executor.map(sample_function, numbers1):
        future = pool2.submit(sample_function2, result, lock)  # Pass args like this.
        futures.append(future.result())  # Must call result(), but value always None.

print("Everything is done ... checking results now!")
print(final_results)
```

Output:

```
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0 and argument 1
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1 and argument 2
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2 and argument 3
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1 and argument 4
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2 and argument 5
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0
Starting execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0 and argument 6
Starting execution of thread from 2nd pool with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 and working on number 1
Completing execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0
Starting execution of thread from 2nd pool with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 and working on number 4
Completing execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0
Starting execution of thread from 2nd pool with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 and working on number 9
Completing execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1
Starting execution of thread from 2nd pool with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 and working on number 16
Completing execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0
Starting execution of thread from 2nd pool with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 and working on number 25
Completing execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1
About to finish executing for thread name ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0
Starting execution of thread from 2nd pool with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 and working on number 36
Completing execution of thread with the name ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0
Everything is done ... checking results now!
{1: 2, 4: 8, 9: 18, 16: 32, 25: 50, 36: 72}
```